# GeoServer: Creating pie charts using SLD

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, chart

I have created a layer in QGIS using pie charts as below:

[image]

I wanted to export this style to SLD and import it into GeoServer and then apply it to a WMS.
The export from QGIS to SLD does not work correctly. The exported SLD does not take into account the diagram and is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Layer</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Layer</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f7f7f7</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#525252</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

So I tried to write myself an SLD displaying pie charts with only two attributes `A` and `B` to start with based on what I found here https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/charting.html. However the result I get are only grey squares.
This is the code that I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name></Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Pie charts</Name>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#d3eeda</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke />
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <PointSymbolizer>
            <Geometry>
              <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:Function>
           </Geometry>
           <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
                  xlink:href="http://chart?cht=p&amp;chf=bg,s,#bfbf15&amp;chd=t:${A},${B}&amp;chl=A|B&amp;chs=200x100&amp;chco=1e1ec3,c51313&amp;chtt=A+B" />
                <Format>application/chart</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

This is the result that I get in GeoServer:

[image]

What do I need to modify in the code to have pie charts as desired?

Comment: Did you install the chart extension? It's required to render pie charts.

Comment: @AndreaAime Yes I already downloaded and installed the content of geoserver-2.21.1-charts-plugin.zip found here https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.21.1/extensions/ I use GeoServer 2.21.1